# How to turing reduce equivalent languages $Q$ to infinite language $I$

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, reductions

Given two languages:

$Q= \{(\langle M_1 \rangle , \langle M_2 \rangle ) \mid L(M_1) = L(M_2)\}$

$I= \{\langle M \rangle \mid \;\vert L(M) \vert = \infty \}$

I'm trying to Turing reduce $Q$ to $I$ ($Q \le_T I$), not the other way around as solved [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/45092/proof-by-turing-reduction/45097)

Any ideas on how to solve this? What exactly will the Turing machine do here and which part is getting solved by the mysterious Oracle?

Comment: @DavidRicherby, that question asks on the other direction $I \le Q$, and a comment there asks the OP to post a new question if he wants to ask about the $Q\le I$ direction.

Comment: @RanG. Ah, that's what I didn't spot. The edit makes that clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $M_1$ and $M_2$ you construct a machine $M$ that on input $w$ does the following:

1. it runs $M_1$ on the first $w$ inputs ($\epsilon$,0,1,00,01,..) for $w$ steps each.

   1. if  $M_1$ accepts some input, you run $M_2$ on the same input and check it accepts too. (note, $M_2$ may not halt!)
   2. If $M_1$ rejects some input, you run $M_2$ for $w$ steps and verify it doesn't accept during that time.
2. you do the same with $M_2$: run $w$ steps on each of the first $w$ inputs, and verify everything works, or reject otherwise
3. if all checks pass - accept. Otherwise reject.

The idea is the following: as long as $M_1$ and $M_2$ behave the same, you will keep accepting all $w$'s. but as long as you find a difference, then you will reject that $w$ and all inputs $w'>w$, thus the accepted language becomes finite. You should be careful because machines may not halt. For instance, $M_1$ may reject some input, but $M_2$ won't halt on it -- still, they both "reject" it, and this case should be carefully analyzed.

Comment: Can I put it like this? Please correct me if I'm doing something wrong:
Create TM $M'$ that runs $M$ here for $Q$ as a subprogram. It takes input $w$ and checks if $M_1$ accept and then if the same $w$ gets accepted by $M_2$. Also if $w$ gets rejected by $M_1$ double check if it gets rejected by $M_2$. Do the same thing vice verse with $M_2$ as described by you in (1.) and (2.). How does this now proof that $\in I$? Can I just ask an oracle $I$ if $\in I$?

Comment: I think you can do without the second part of step 1, since this will be checked by step 2 (and conversely for the implicit second part of step two). ---  I do not understand what problem there is with halting in your last two sentences. If one accept and the other rejects or does not halt, you have a difference and not halting is the proper behavior.

Comment: @KevinGoedecke Try to understand what is written, The idea of the proof is as
follows. Suppose $v$ is a number that belongs to one language and not
the other, and $n$ is the number of steps needed by the machine $M_1$
or $M_2$ that recognizes it. Then the machine $M$ will not accept any
input larger than both $v$ and $n$. Thus it will recognize only a
finite language.  Conversely, if both languages are equal, them $M$
recognizes all inputs, hence infinitely many. Thus a pair
$(⟨M_1⟩,⟨M_2⟩)$ is in Q iff the language accepted by $M$ is infinite.